# Как получить результат из промиса без async/await

Tags: javascript, promise, return

Есть две функции (код упрощен):

`server.js:`

```
  getData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 2, 3]), 2000);
    });
  }
```

`client.js`

```
  requestData = () => {
    return getData().then((res) => res);
  }
```

**Необходимо, чтобы ф-я `requestData` возвращала `[1, 2, 3]`, как это сделать? `async/await` использовать нельзя.**

`Expected:`

```
console.log(requestData()); //[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Это технически невозможно, использование then/async/await — это **единственный возможный** способ получить результат асинхронной функции

Comment: @andreymal так then использовать можно

Comment: Ну значит `requestData().then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: `console.log(requestData())` - в таком виде - никак

Comment: @andreymal а нельзя сделать так, чтобы requestData() можно было использовать без .then?
Например, если из getData уже возвращать промис с .then?

Comment: @trek89 как мы с Grundy уже написали — это технически невозможно

Comment: @andreymal, печально. Но спасибо за ответ!)

Comment: @trek89, если сделать без then и async/await - самоцель, то можно прибегнуть к событиям.